# Custom shortcut for TotalCommander and invoking TortoiseGit log at current folder

Tags: tortoisegit, total-commander

I'm going over this topic everytime I setup new computer and I always have to make reasearch that takes me up to 20 mins. I like to use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) together with [TotalCommander](https://www.ghisler.com/).

To easy up navigation, I would like to open TortoiseGit - `log`, at currently opened folder. And ideally I would like to do that without touching any button (by mouse), instead just pressing keyboard shortcut.

**How can this be achieved?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to this question has 2 parts, first we need to understand, how to open TortoiseGit - log at current folder. It can be done by running following exe (full and shortened path):

- `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:.`
- `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:.`

Now we need to add this path to the TotalCommander. New custom command can be added as:

1. Go to Configuration, Misc.
2. Create new hotkey (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
3. Press Magnifier to select command
4. In Category select `usercmd.ini` and press `New...`
5. Insert your command (e.g. `TortoiseGitProc /command:log /path:.`), press OK
6. Aplly shortcut (by green mark) and press OK

---

[image: TotalCommander misc]
[image: TotalCommander choose command]
[image: TotalCommander edit command]